# Difference Between Single and Double Quoted Strings in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, string

Is there any difference between single and double quoted strings in ActionScript?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use either as delimiter for a string. They are however not interchangeable, i.e. you can't start a string with an apostrophe and end it with a quotation mark.

The only difference is which characters you need to escape. Inside a string delimited by quotation marks you need to escape quotation marks but not apostrophes, and vice versa.

To put the text `He said "It's all right" and laughed.` in a string you can use:

```
"He said \"It's all right\" and laughed."
```

or:

```
'He said "It\'s all right" and laughed.'
```

Answer (score 4):

No.

// * required - at least 15 characters

Comment: That's the first time I see comments in something a compiler will never look at. ^^

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.

This is from [ActionScript: The definitive Guide](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/web2/action/ch04_05.htm):

String is the datatype used for textual data (letters, punctuation marks, and other characters). A string literal is any combination of characters enclosed in quotation marks:

```
    "asdfksldfsdfeoif"  // A frustrated string
    "greetings"         // A friendly string
    "moock@moock.org"   // A self-promotional string
    "123"               // It may look like a number, but it's a string
    'singles'           // Single quotes are acceptable too
```

Answer (score 2):

No, apart from it being easier to include single quotes in double quoted strings and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In Actionscript itself, there are not differences, other than the availability of the unused delimiter without escape characters.

In Flash Builder, a common AS3 authoring IDE for Flex, autocomplete for compatible event types (e.g., `Event.COMPLETE`) on `addEventListener` [will not work](http://stevenxu.ca/post/37445951159/autocomplete-addeventlistener-constants-in-as3) if those event types are defined with single quotes rather that double quotes.

Suppose you have a class a tag it as dispatching a particular event type with the Flex meta tag.

```
[Event(name="foo",type="pkg.events.Constants")]
class SomethingThatDispatchesFoo extends EventDispatcher {
```

If your event constant class is structured like this:

```
class Constants {
  public static const FOO:String = 'foo';
}
```

Then autocomplete will give you `'foo'`. However, if it's structured like this:

```
class Constants {
  public static const FOO:String = "foo";
}
```

The autocomplete will give you `Constants.FOO`.