# Difference between 'hello' and "hello" in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference Between Single and Double Quoted Strings in ActionScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073537/difference-between-single-and-double-quoted-strings-in-actionscript)

Hello I have a simple question that I hope you can answer. I have been programming in actionscript for three months and I am very new to a lot of the details. I was programming in java in which there is an important difference between 'hello' and "hello".

**So my question is:
In actionScript is it the same to use 'Hello' and "Hello". If not what are the differences???**

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the same thing. I'm sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073537/difference-between-single-and-double-quoted-strings-in-actionscript) will answer your question, since it's been asked before.

Comment: Ok thanks, finally i got a good answer... i searched using the "" and ' ' and no the quote term!