# What's the difference between ' and "?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

In actionscript, some code goes like this: `trace();`.  So in trace statements I can both use an apostrophe or quotes.  So is there any difference if I'm using each one?  Example: difference between `trace("Works!");` and `trace('Works!');`.  Is there any reason why each works and not just one?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ef8.html

Comment: @user2246674 Thanks!  Complete link to strings reference!

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073537/difference-between-single-and-double-quoted-strings-in-actionscript  - google can help you find these answers quicker than making a new question.

Comment: Duplicate question, then!  I tried searching this in google (exact search: ' flash difference between ' and " ' but nothing came up!

Comment: @Abe "actionscript quote reference" or "actionscript quote syntax" might be better search phrases - same with operators and such; best resource for syntax is usually the authoritative reference or a companion guide.

Comment: @user2246674 Okay, thank you, I even flagged my own question as duplicate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is the quote token and required escaping of such. (That is, *unlike* some languages, there are no special rules between the two forms.)

The AS3 developer guide [Creating Strings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ef8.html) article discussed when using one quote over the other is preferable - it all comes down to when the particular quote needs to be escaped.

> You may choose to use single quotation marks or double quotation marks based on any single or double quotation marks that exist in a string literal, as in the following:
>
> `var str1:String = "ActionScript <span class='heavy'>3.0</span>";`
>
> `var str2:String = '<item id="155">banana</item>';`

Comment: Nicely explained!  I've been wondering how to put quotes in strings!  (Will accept answer is 6 minutes...)